# Pandas to_sql with parameterized data types like NUMERIC(10,2)

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

Pandas has a lovely `to_sql` method for writing dataframes to any RDBMS supported by SQLAlchemy.

Say I have a dataframe generated thusly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([-1.04, 0.70, 0.11, -0.43, 1.0], columns=['value'])
```

If I try to write it to the database without any special behavior, I get a column type of double precision:

```
df.to_sql('foo_test', an_engine)
```

If I wanted a different datatype, I could specify it (this works fine):

```
df.to_sql('foo_test', an_engine, dtype={'value': sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC})
```

But if I want to **set the precision and scale of the `NUMERIC` column, it blows up in my face**:

```
df.to_sql('foo_test', an_engine, dtype={'value': sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(10,2)})


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-dc008463fbfc> in <module>()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame([-1.04, 0.70, 0.11, -0.43, 1.0], columns=['value'])
----> 2 df.to_sql('foo_test', cosd_engine, dtype={'value': sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(10,2)})

/Users/igazit/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    964             self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,
    965             index=index, index_label=index_label, chunksize=chunksize,
--> 966             dtype=dtype)
    967 
    968     def to_pickle(self, path):

/Users/igazit/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    536     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    537                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 538                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    539 
    540 

/Users/igazit/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1162             import sqlalchemy.sql.type_api as type_api
   1163             for col, my_type in dtype.items():
-> 1164                 if not issubclass(my_type, type_api.TypeEngine):
   1165                     raise ValueError('The type of %s is not a SQLAlchemy '
   1166                                      'type ' % col)

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

I'm trying to dig into why the type for `sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC` passes the test on 1164, while `sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(10,2)` doesn't. They do have different types (`sqlalchemy.sql.visitors.VisitableType` vs `sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.NUMERIC`).

Any clues would be much appreciated!

Comment: A recent bug was filed that is similar to what you are describing  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9083

Comment: @BobHaffner that seems on-point. Want to answer this question with that link so I can give you the big green checkmark? :)

Comment: The answer provides a good work around for now, and the fix itself will be included in the upcoming 0.16 version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: this bug is fixed for pandas >= 0.16.0

---

This is post about a recent pandas bug with the same error with 0.15.2.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9083

A Collaborator suggests a to_sql monkey patch as a way to solve it

```
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable

def to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists='fail', index=True,
           index_label=None, schema=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None):
    """
    patched version of https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.15.2/pandas/io/sql.py#L1129
    """
    if dtype is not None:
        from sqlalchemy.types import to_instance, TypeEngine
        for col, my_type in dtype.items():
            if not isinstance(to_instance(my_type), TypeEngine):
                raise ValueError('The type of %s is not a SQLAlchemy '
                                 'type ' % col)

    table = SQLTable(name, self, frame=frame, index=index,
                     if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
                     schema=schema, dtype=dtype)
    table.create()
    table.insert(chunksize)
    # check for potentially case sensitivity issues (GH7815)
    if name not in self.engine.table_names(schema=schema or self.meta.schema):
        warnings.warn("The provided table name '{0}' is not found exactly "
                      "as such in the database after writing the table, "
                      "possibly due to case sensitivity issues. Consider "
                      "using lower case table names.".format(name), UserWarning)

pd.io.sql.SQLDatabase.to_sql = to_sql
```

Comment: This function works out of the box, but the bug still exists as far as I am concerned.